# Adding symbol (e.g. @) in front of slug in NextJS route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am trying to add `@` in front of a slug URL. For example: `https://example.com/@username`.

I tried `@[username].js` but that is not working.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) and some regex. Next.js uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) under the hood.

```js
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:userId(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/:id*',
        destination: "/user/:userId/:id*",
      }
    ]
  }
```

On client side use `next/link`:

```js
<Link href={`@${userId}`}>
  <a>user</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Wait, how does the folder structure would look like?

Comment: Like your normal nextjs page folder.