# How can I make a dynamic route start with an @ symbol? Like "mywebsite.com/@username"

Tags: next.js, vercel

My goal is to have two kinds of dynamic routes on the same path. I want:

- `mywebsite.com/@username` to send people to `/pages/[username].tsx`
- `mywebsite.com/page-slug` to send people to `/pages/[pageSlug].tsx`

I tried creating two files:

- `/pages/[pageSlug].tsx`
- `/pages/[...username].tsx`

So that `[pageSlug].tsx` would have priority, and then everything else would go to `[...username].tsx`, where I would extract the `username` from the path and render the page.

It works great locally, but on vercel `mywebsite.com/@username` pages return 404 error.

---

I have also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389057/adding-symbol-eg-in-front-of-slug-in-nextjs-route) advice about doing this with url rewrites, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have created two files:

- `/pages/[pageSlug].tsx`
- `/pages/user/[username].tsx`

Set up the rewrites in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:username(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/:id*',
        destination: "/user/:username/:id*",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And set up the links to the user profiles like so:

```
<Link href="/user/[username]" as={`@${post.author.username}`}>
  {post.author.username}
</Link>
```

Just loading the `http://localhost:3080/@lumen` works, but when I click on a link I'm getting:

> Error: The provided `as` value (/@lumen) is incompatible with the `href` value (/user/[username]). Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/incompatible-href-as

How can I make this work with the rewrites (or in any other way)? Any advice?

Comment: According to the docs, rewrites are applied to client-side routing as well. Have you tried not setting the `as` param on the `Link` and just use ``href={`/@${post.author.username}`}``?

Comment: Oh this is perfect, that worked! So obvious, but somehow I assumed that you have to do it the other way, with "as". Thank you so much for your help!